# How do I add Multiple AI Difficulties to my func computerPlay() in my UIViewController? I am creating a tic tac toe game in UIKit

Tags: swiftui, uiviewcontroller, uikit, tic-tac-toe

How do I add Multiple AI Difficulties to my func computerPlay() in my UIViewController? I am creating a tic tac toe game in UIKit
I know how to do it in swiftui from another project. I don't know how to change their names to the correct code in my project. I have tried and kept failing. Right now when you play against the computer and try to lose, majority of the time you will get a draw or a force win. Please help.

```
//
//  xoGame.swift
//  TicBones
//
//  Created by Carissa Richardson on 12/8/22.
//

import UIKit
import SwiftUI
class xoGame: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var playerScore3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var a2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var a3: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var b1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var b2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var b3: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var c1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var c2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var c3: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundLabel: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var a1: UIImageView!
    
    
    var gameP1 = "o"
    var playerChoices: [Box2] = []
    var computerChoices: [Box2] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createTap(on: a1, type: .one)
        createTap(on: a2, type: .two)
        createTap(on: a3, type: .three)
        createTap(on: b1, type: .four)
        createTap(on: b2, type: .five)
        createTap(on: b3, type: .six)
        createTap(on: c1, type: .seven)
        createTap(on: c2, type: .eight)
        createTap(on: c3, type: .nine)
        
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var computerScore3: UILabel!
    
    func createTap(on imageView: UIImageView, type box: Box2){
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.boxClicked(_:)))
        tap.name = box.rawValue
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    @objc func boxClicked(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        //        print("Box: \(sender.name) was clicked")
        let selectedBox = getBox(from: sender.name ?? "")
        makeChoice(selectedBox)
        playerChoices.append(Box2(rawValue: sender.name!)!)
        checkIfWon()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            self.computerPlay()
        }
    }
    func computerPlay(){
        var availableSpaces = [UIImageView]()
        var availableBoxes = [Box2]()
        for name in Box2.allCases {
            let box = getBox(from: name.rawValue)
            if box.image == nil {
                availableSpaces.append(box)
                availableBoxes.append(name)
            }
        }
        
        guard availableBoxes.count > 0 else { return }

// THIS IS WERE I NEED HELP!
// If AI can win, than win
    //If AI cant win, than block
    // If AI cant block, then take middle source
    //If AI cant take middle square, take random available square

 let randIndex = Int.random(in: 0 ..< availableSpaces.count)
        makeChoice(availableSpaces[randIndex])
        computerChoices.append(availableBoxes[randIndex])
        checkIfWon()
    }
    
    func makeChoice(_ selectedBox: UIImageView) {
        guard selectedBox.image == nil else { return }
        
        if gameP1 == "x" {
            selectedBox.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "O")
            gameP1 = "o"
        } else {
            selectedBox.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "x")
            gameP1 = "x"
        }
    }
    func checkIfWon() {
        var correct = [[Box2]]()
        let firstRow: [Box2] = [.one, .two, .three]
        let secondRow: [Box2] = [.four, .five, .six]
        let thirdRow: [Box2] = [.seven, .eight, .nine]
        
        let firstCol: [Box2] = [.one, .four, .seven]
        let secondCol: [Box2] = [.two, .five, .six]
        let thirdCol: [Box2] = [.three, .six, .nine]
        
        let backwardSlash: [Box2] = [.one, .five, .nine]
        let forwardSlash: [Box2] = [.three, .five, .seven]
        
        correct.append(firstRow)
        correct.append(secondRow)
        correct.append(thirdRow)
        correct.append(firstCol)
        correct.append(secondCol)
        correct.append(thirdCol)
        correct.append(backwardSlash)
        correct.append(forwardSlash)
        
        for valid in correct {
            let userMatch = playerChoices.filter { valid.contains($0) }.count
            let computerMatch = computerChoices.filter { valid.contains($0) }.count
            
            if userMatch == valid.count {
                playerScore3.text = String((Int(playerScore3.text ?? "0") ?? 0) + 1)
                resetGame()
                break
            } else if computerMatch == valid.count {
                computerScore3.text = String((Int(computerScore3.text ?? "0") ?? 0) + 1)
                resetGame()
                break
            } else if computerChoices.count + playerChoices.count == 9 {
                resetGame()
                break
            }
        }
        
    }
    func resetGame() {
        for name in Box2.allCases {
            let box = getBox(from: name.rawValue)
            box.image = nil
        }
        gameP1 = "o"
        playerChoices = []
        computerChoices = []
    }
    
    func getBox(from name: String) -> UIImageView {
        let box = Box2(rawValue: name) ?? .one
        
        switch box {
        case .one:
            return a1
        case .two:
            return a2
        case .three:
            return a3
        case .four:
            return b1
        case .five:
            return b2
        case .six:
            return b3
        case .seven:
            return c1
        case .eight:
            return c2
        case .nine:
            return c3
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func dice(_ sender: Any) {
        backgroundLabel.image = [ #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2022-08-10 at 10.52.27 PM"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2022-08-10 at 12.18.19 AM"),  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2022-07-04 at 3.43.07 PM"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2022-08-10 at 10.53.00 PM"),  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2022-08-10 at 11.56.06 PM"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2022-07-04 at 3.11.02 PM"),  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Ice Cream In Paper Cut Background"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2022-07-04 at 3.11.02 PM"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2022-08-10 at 12.28.13 AM"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2022-08-10 at 10.52.03 PM"),  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_9062"),  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_9064"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_9061"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_9063"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_9065"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2022-07-04 at 3.10.05 PM"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backPinkbirth"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "skybackground"), ][Int.random(in: 0...17)]
    }
    
    @IBAction func refresh(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    enum Box2: String, CaseIterable{
        case one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to create a weaker AI or is the problem that you don't know how you can choose which AI to play against?

Comment: *"I know how to do it in swiftui..."* -- then post the SwiftUI code and show us what you're having trouble converting.

Comment: I want to make the AI more difficult rn it's hard to force the computer to win. @eligolf

Comment: @CarissaRichardson, it is easy to make it win in tic tac toe, it is hard to make it play less optimal. Watch any tutorial on minimax algorithm, or in this game you can even hard code the possible moves.